# Getting a drop down select list to stay extended after selection

Tags: jquery, html

I have a drop down box in this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/DFBdk/1/ - that holds a list of files that can be deleted. So in the actual application,  for each file you want to delete you drop down the list, pick the file, it gets deleted, and the drop down list closes.  Then you have to drop it down again and pick another file if you want to delete another one.  What I would like  is for the list to stay down so you can just click one file after another to delete many files. To close the list when you're done you would click the drop down arrow again.

Does anyone see a way, using jQuery perhaps,  to implement this behavior?  I've tried fooling with selectedIndex, but that just controls the item shown in the drop down when it's closed.

Thanks

```
<select id="delete_dropdown" title="delete a page" name="loads">
    <option value="" selected="selected">DELETE</option>
    <option value="DigDil">DigDil</option>
    <option value="a2">a2</option>
    <option value="bob">bob</option>
    <option value="box1">box1</option>
    <option value="box12a">box12a</option>
    <option value="box12d">box12d</option>
    <option value="box17">box17</option>
    <option value="box18">box18</option>
    <option value="box1z">box1z</option>
    <option value="box32">box32</option>
    <option value="box34">box34</option>
    <option value="box789">box789</option>
    <option value="box88">box88</option>
    <option value="box92">box92</option>
    <option value="box93">box93</option>
    <option value="box94">box94</option>
    <option value="boxaa">boxaa</option>
    <option value="boxbb">boxbb</option>
    <option value="boxcc">boxcc</option>
    <option value="boxdd">boxdd</option>
    <option value="boxee">boxee</option>
    <option value="bx12">bx12</option>
    <option value="c1">c1</option>
    <option value="cateye">cateye</option>
    <option value="cdf">cdf</option>
    <option value="dfr">dfr</option>
    <option value="dg">dg</option>
    <option value="dg4">dg4</option>
    <option value="dg5">dg5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using the `multiple` attribute ?

[image]

[**example :**](http://jsfiddle.net/DFBdk/5/)

Comment: Yes!  That's perfect.  Thanks.  By the way, how did you generate the "torn paper" effect on your post?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `select` element. Use `div`s. Make a container and house your options inside it with a wrapping `div`. Then have a button animate to show the list of `div`s. Then all you'll need is some CSS to make them look pretty.

Something like this:

```
<style>
    .container div {
       display:none;
    }
</style>


<div class="container"
    <div>option1</div>
    <div>option2</div>
    <div>option3</div>
    <div>option4</div>
    <div>option5</div>
    <div>option6</div>
</div>

$("button").on("click", function() {
    $(".container").children().toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a list element instead of select element and show/hide them when clicking a button like this

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('label:first').on('click', function () {
    $('ul').toggle();
});
$('ul li').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
$('label:last').on('click', function () {
    $('li.selected').remove();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DFBdk/4/)